# Scikit-Learn Post pruning in RandomForestClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, pruning

Does the RandomForestClassifier() in scikit-learn support post-pruning? So there are parameters such as max_depth etc but they are more on the pre-pruning side.

So is it possible to build out the tree as far as possible and then prune the tree after in order to avoid overfitting.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not present in current versions. There are [active](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6557) [issues](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4630) on github regrading this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vivek.